# Dynamic YASnippet, inserting method name and arguments

Tags: javascript, java, emacs, yasnippet

How is it possible to access the name of the method (and its arguments) when inserting a YASnippet in a Java (or JavaScript) code block?

The goal is to be able to expand

```
logm
```

into (for example):

```
log("notify() called with: " + "context = [" + context + "]");
```

if inserted in the body of function:

```
public void notify(final EventHandlerContext context) {
....
}
```

(Such a live template exists in IntelliJ IDEA.)

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate arbitrary lisp code in the snippet.  So, if you have a function to grab the method name/arguments it can be called from the snippet code.  For example, here is a quick attempt to get the method name -- you could probably find a better function somewhere in `cc-cmds` or `eclim` libraries.

```
(defun java-method-name ()
  (save-excursion
    (c-beginning-of-defun)
    (when (re-search-forward "\\([A-Za-z]+\\)(")
      (match-string 1))))
```

snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: logm
# key: logm
# --
log("`(java-method-name)`() called with: " + ${1:etc:..})
```

Comment: In order to fully address the quesiton, would you be able to spot functions which would get the params' names?